# PIVOT dinâmico SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela que armazena os códigos de barras EST_PROD_CD_BARRA dos produtos, porém, gostaria de trazer todos os EANs de um item em apenas uma linha com base no id (cd_prod), visto que, um produto pode ter n códigos de barras.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao pesquisar verifiquei que uma forma de retornar os vários resultados em apenas uma linha poderia ser utilizando o PIVOT (recurso do SQLServer), tentei aplicar mas não consegui realizar com sucesso. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
declare @colunas_pivot as nvarchar(max), @comando_sql  as nvarchar(max)
set @colunas_pivot =
stuff((
    select
        distinct ',' + quotename(CD_PROD)
    from EST_PROD_CD_BARRA
    for xml path('')
), 1, 1, '')
set @comando_sql = '
select * from (
    SELECT 
        B.CD_PROD,
        B.TP_CD_BARRA,
        B.CD_BARRA
    FROM EST_PROD_CD_BARRA B
    GROUP BY B.CD_PROD,B.CD_BARRA
) em_linha
pivot (MAX(CD_BARRA) for CD_PROD in (' + @colunas_pivot + ')) em_colunas
order by 1'
print @comando_sql
execute(@comando_sql)
go
```

Comment: Que resultado lhe dá? Consegue colocar um exemplo do resultado que espera?